# How to remove element from json object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, array-splice

I am using angularjs to integrate my apis.

I have a grid table and DELETE button in each row.

my controller have following code:

```
$scope.singleAppDetails = {};

$scope.removeRow = function(detail, index){             

       var delRes =  $http.delete($scope.appUrl + detail.id, detail);
        delRes.success(function (data, status, headers, configs) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        delRes.error(function (data, status, headers, configs) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        $scope.singleAppDetails.splice(index, 1);
    };
```

and $scope.singleAppDetails contains:

```
Object {id: "553e20fce4b0f4eb7d13fd13", name: "Amazon", appId: "3ebc86ea-62a7-419f-9f60-dc88b66efa6e", secret: "n9prQ8YSdcxuBAcQ1PX4DUeOUBZoAKqBHnCONrueGoUTE8pqFZ", domain: "e-commerce"}
```

But i am getting "TypeError: $scope.singleAppDetails.splice is not a function"
error in console.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me! What do you want to do exactly? - please share your html code that has `ng-repeat` -HTH ;).

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because splice is a method for Arrays only and $scope.singleAppDetails is an object in your code.

Comment: so is there any way to delete an element from json object ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 0):

`splice()` is a Array function. See the [documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

You define singleAppDetails as an object:

```
$scope.singleAppDetails = {};
```

**Answer:** Delete the id with:

```
delete $scope.singleAppDetails.id;
```

See this example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/laqarodabe/1/).